# JavaScript - find a word phrase and add css

Tags: javascript, css

I need a javascript solution to search all the text in a < div class="page-content entry-content" > of a website find only the phrase "FuzzyBears" and make it lowercase using CSS style .fuzzy {font-weight:500; text-transform: lowercase;} and also change "Bears" in the phrase to use CSS style .bear {font-weight:800; color:red}, without changing any instances of the word "bear" used in sentences that is not part of the phrase "FuzzyBears".

So instead of "FuzzyBears"

It reads as "fuzzy**bears**" and "bear" in red.

And any use of the word bear (without fuzzy before it) in a sentence is left untouched.

Here's what I have tried working with, but with no success as of yet.

```js
function Change(word) {
  //find all html elements on the page inside the body tag
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll("body *");
  // get our replacement ready
  let span = "<span class='bearboldred'>" + word + "</span>";
  //loop through all the elements
  for (let x = 0; x < elems.length; x++) {
    // for each element, 'split' by the word we're looking for, then 'join' it back with the replacement
    elems[x].innerHTML = elems[x].innerHTML.split(word).join(span);
  }
}

Change('bear');
```

```css
h1 {font-weight:300}

h1.bearboldred,
h2.bearboldred,
h3.bearboldred,
h4.bearboldred,
h5.bearboldred,
h6.bearboldred,
p.bearboldred,
.bearboldred {
  color: red;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>Welcome to FuzzyBear</h1> 
<p>Where you can learn all about bears and bear cubs.</p> </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Mickey, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you pls provide the code or what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hey Ram, I added what I have so far... but it's not working as hoped.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform. Do you have a question? [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, based on your question, I think you can separate the word `Fuzzybear`
into two parts:

- lowercase (`Fuzzy` -> `fuzzy`)
- boldRed (`bear`)

First, you can standardize the word which you want to modify to lowercase with regex.

Then, do the part you did.

Here is the example, hope this helps!

```js
function Change(lowercase, boldRed) {

  let word = lowercase + boldRed

  // find all html elements on the page inside the body tag
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll("body *");

  // prepare the replacement part
  let span = `<span>${lowercase}</span><span class='bearboldred'>${boldRed}</span>`;

  // loop through all the elements
  for (let x = 0; x < elems.length; x++) {
    // find the keyword you want to replace and replace it
    const regex = /(FuzzyBear|Fuzzybear|fuzzyBear)/g;
    elems[x].innerHTML = elems[x].innerHTML.replace(regex, word)
    elems[x].innerHTML = elems[x].innerHTML.split(word).join(span);
  }
}

Change('fuzzy', 'bear');
```

```css
h1 {font-weight:300}

h1.bearboldred,
h2.bearboldred,
h3.bearboldred,
h4.bearboldred,
h5.bearboldred,
h6.bearboldred,
p.bearboldred,
.bearboldred {
  color: red;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>Welcome to FuzzyBear</h1> 
<p>Where you can learn all about bears, bear cubs, and Fuzzybear.</p> </div>
```

Comment: Hey Vanngoh, Thank you! That's definetly doing what I need it to. One last thing... cna you show me how to target the contents of a div instead of the body?  

Example: 

Currently your code has: let elems = document.querySelectorAll("body *");

How do I change this to target < div class="page-content entry-content" >

Comment: Hey Vannogh, I really appreciate the help!!! This working just like I needed it to after changing   //let elems = document.querySelectorAll("body *"); TO THIS  let elems = document.getElementsByClassName('page-content');

Comment: I'm glad that helps! And yes Mickey, you can get the document by specifying the class name as you mentioned :)